# Is there any possible way to create a hitbox using tkinter frame?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter frame and 2 sprites, I can easily make my vel = 0 when I'm at the exact pos of the wall. The issue is, that inside the sprite (I need the character to stop when he hits the edge of the wall).

```
import tkinter ##SETUP##
from tkinter import *
import threading
from threading import Timer

window = Tk() ##WINDOW SETUP##
window.title("Project Gladiator, Pre-Alpha 0.3")
window.config(bg = "white")

frame = Frame(window, width = 1000, height = 1000)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
frame.focus_set()

Px = 50 #char pos ##VARIABLES##
Py = 50 #char pos
X = 5 #char Xcel
Xchange = 5 #sets X
Direction = "Down" #different sprites based on movement
Level = 0 #used for collision (starts from 0)

PlayerF1 = PhotoImage(file = "Mainchar.png") #replace by each frame ##MAIN CHAR##
Playerd = Label(frame, image = PlayerF1)
Playerd.place(x = Px, y = Py)

w = False #movement button presses
a = False #movement button presses
s = False #movement button presses
d = False #movement button presses
##########################################################################---LEVEL---DRAWING---##########################################################################
#TEXTURES#
Wallimg = PhotoImage(file = "Lategame-tile.png")
#TESTLEVELONE#
Walltest = Label(window, image = Wallimg)
WalltestX = 30
WalltestY = 30

##########################################################################---MOVEMENT---##########################################################################
def keypress(event):
    if event.char == "w":
        global w
        global a
        global s
        global d
        global Xchange
        w = True

    elif event.char == "a":
        a = True

    elif event.char == "s":
        s = True

    elif event.char == "d":
        d = True

    elif event.char == "`":
        Console = Tk()
        Console.title("Console")
        Console.config(bg = "green")
        Output = Label(Console, text = "Output", bg = "green", fg = "yellow", font = "none 9")
        #output goes here...
        Input = Label(Console, text = "Input", bg = "green", fg = "yellow", font = "none 9")
        Commandline = Entry(Console, bg = "white")
        def SubmitCommand():
            Command = Commandline.get()
            print(f"Command Submitted \"{Command}\"")
            Commandline.delete(0, END)
        Commandsub = Button(Console, text = "Submit", bg = "green", fg = "yellow", command = SubmitCommand)

        Output.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        Input.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        Commandline.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        Commandsub.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

def keyup(event):
    if event.char == "w":
        global w
        global a
        global s
        global d
        w = False

    elif event.char == "a":
        a = False

    elif event.char == "s":
        s = False

    elif event.char == "d":
        d = False

def wpress():
    def wcheck():
        if w == True:
            global Direction
            global Py
            global Px
            global X
            global Xchange
            X = Xchange
            Direction = "Up"
            Py = Py - X
            if Level == 0 and Py == 30 and Px == 30:
                Py = Py + X
            Playerd.place(x = Px, y = Py)
        elif w == False:
            X = 0

        if a == True:
            X = Xchange
            Direction = "Right"
            Px = Px - X
            if Level == 0 and Py == 30 and Px == 30:
                Px = Px + X
            Playerd.place(x = Px, y = Py)
        elif w == False:
            X = 0

        if s == True:
            X = Xchange
            Direction = "Down"
            Py = Py + X
            if Level == 0 and Py == 30 and Px == 30:
                Py = Py - X
            Playerd.place(x = Px, y = Py)
        elif w == False:
            X = 0

        if d == True:
            X = Xchange
            Direction = "Left"
            Px = Px + X
            if Level == 0 and Py == 30 and Px == 30:
                Px = Px - X
            Playerd.place(x = Px, y = Py)
        elif w == False:
            X = 0

        wpress()

    c = Timer(0.001, wcheck)
    c.start()


frame.bind("<Key>", keypress)
frame.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)

wpress()
##########################################################################---END---MOVEMENT---##########################################################################
##########################################################################---LEVELS---##########################################################################
def DrawTEST1(): #wall test
    Walltest.place(x = WalltestX, y = WalltestY)

DrawTEST1()
window.mainloop()
```

The focus is on this part

```
def wpress():
    def wcheck():
        if w == True:
            global Direction
            global Py
            global Px
            global X
            global Xchange
            X = Xchange
            Direction = "Up"
            Py = Py - X
            if Level == 0 and Py == 30 and Px == 30:
                Py = Py + X
            Playerd.place(x = Px, y = Py)
        elif w == False:
            X = 0

        if a == True:
            X = Xchange
            Direction = "Right"
            Px = Px - X
            if Level == 0 and Py == 30 and Px == 30:
                Px = Px + X
            Playerd.place(x = Px, y = Py)
        elif w == False:
            X = 0

        if s == True:
            X = Xchange
            Direction = "Down"
            Py = Py + X
            if Level == 0 and Py == 30 and Px == 30:
                Py = Py - X
            Playerd.place(x = Px, y = Py)
        elif w == False:
            X = 0

        if d == True:
            X = Xchange
            Direction = "Left"
            Px = Px + X
            if Level == 0 and Py == 30 and Px == 30:
                Px = Px - X
            Playerd.place(x = Px, y = Py)
        elif w == False:
            X = 0

        wpress()

    c = Timer(0.001, wcheck)
    c.start()


frame.bind("<Key>", keypress)
```

I have been pulling my hair out on this one for quite some time. If anyone can help then that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured it out yet, but since I encountered something in the same vain as this, I'd like to share what I came up with. 
Just keep in mind that Tkinter isn't exactly made for this sort of thing, and something like Pygame would be a better choice.

**The simple way:**
If your sprite is a simple one, like a square shape, just points in each direction slightly outside your sprite, and on each move check if that point is overlapping with the wall or not.
Example: if your sprite is 25x25, then you could have the center as x, y, and the point for collision detection to the right could then be x+26, y. The left could then be x-26, y.
The problem here is that you are using labels in a frame, so you'd either have to figure out the position with trail and error, or use the .bbox method.

**The slightly more complicated way (but ultimately the easier way):**
If your sprite has somewhat of an odd shape, and you want it to be more accurate, you could put it on a Canvas instead of a Frame. That gives you the option to draw out a polygon that you can trace around the sprite. Then have it move with the sprite, and simply check if that overlaps with a wall, enemy, bullet, trap or whatever else you can think of. This would give you far more flexibility.

Canvas is also a better choice in general if you want to do more complex things, as it allows you to move things around easier, draw out shapes, set tags ect. You can still put labels, buttons and all that good stuff on a canvas if you want those, no need to use a frame unless you are just packing stuff into it.

Lastly I would **highly** recommend using classes, it will make your life so much easier and is one of the major strengths of the language. They can be a bit confusing at first, but it is worth the time it takes to learn many times over. Once you get used to them, you'll wonder how you managed to do anything without them.